# How to screen-capture an entire Bootstrap 3 modal dialog which scrolls off the screen

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3, screen-capture, pagination

I am trying to screen-capture a Bootstrap3 modal dialog that scrolls off the screen vertically.

All the screen capture extensions I have tried in Chrome and Firefox simply capture the visible area of the window, even if I select "entire page".

The scroll bars are present - why can't these utilities tell how tall the modal dialog is, and how can I capture the entire thing in one shot?

(Otherwise I'm going to have to cut pieces and stitch them together!)

Thanks!

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl

Comment: Thanks @makshh, I tried this one but it still only captures the visible portion of the screen, no matter how long the Boostrap modal dialog is.

Comment: Hmm I tried this plugin with smaller width (with horizontal scrollbar) and the output was good.

Comment: @makshh it's something about the way the bootstrap dialog is displayed. Even though it has scroll bars the capture doesn't see its full height.

Comment: Yeah probably. So good luck with this :)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome 59+ supports full-screen capture:

> Developer Tools => Network => Camera Icon => Refresh

Firefox 53+ supports this as well:

> Developer Tools => Camera Icon

**References**

- [What's New In DevTools (Chrome 59)  |  Web  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#screenshots)
- [Taking screenshots - Firefox Developer Tools | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Taking_screenshots)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

As a workaround, I had to:

1. Inspect the modal to find its computed height (I targeted the element with class `modal-dialog` for Bootstrap 4)
2. Inspect the body element of the page and set its height to a value a little bigger than the modal's one (from previous step)

Then the plugins do capture the whole modal as well (I guess they scroll only to the body's computed height).